# Node bcrypt's compare always returns false

Tags: javascript, node.js, bcrypt

I am stumped trying to get my passwords to successfully compare with bcrypt using node.  Maybe I missed something, but on account creation, I do the following within the signup method (with some code abbreviated):

```
bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err, salt) {
               if(err) {

               }
               bcrypt.hash(user.Password, salt, function(err, hash) {
                           console.log('hashing and saving');
                           db.query(db insert code, function (error, rows, fields) {
                                    if(error) {
                                    console.log(error);
                                    res.setHeader('500', { 'Content-Type': 'x-application/json'});
                                    res.send({UserId: 0, ErrorMessage: 'Something terrible happened.'});
                                    } else {
                                    console.log('User created : ' + rows.insertId);
                                    res.setHeader('200', { 'Content-Type': 'x-application/json'});
                                    res.send({UserId: rows.insertId});
                                    }
                                    });
                           });
               });

return next();
```

This all works fine.  My db has the encrypted password.  But when a user signs in, I cannot get a successful result from bcrypt.compare:

```
db.query(get account code, function(error, rows, fields) {
         if(rows.length == 1) {
           bcrypt.compare(request.params.password, rows[0].Password, function(err,res) {
              if(err) { console.log(err.toString()); }
              if(res == true)
              {
                        response.setHeader('200', { 'Content-Type': 'x-application/json' });
                        response.send({result: true});
              } else {
                        response.setHeader('401', { 'Content-Type': 'x-application/json' });
                        console.log('invalid password');
                        response.send({result:false});
                     }
              });
         }
        });

return next();
```

And I always end up with invalid password.  Do I need to take the cleartext password and re-encrypt it before comparing to what I pull out of the database?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

you can skip doing `bcrypt.genSalt` and use `bcrypt.hash(password, 10, function(err, hash) {..});`

your compare function seems good to me.

this is working fine for me:

```
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

bcrypt.hash('mypassword', 10, function(err, hash) {
    if (err) { throw (err); }

    bcrypt.compare('mypassword', hash, function(err, result) {
        if (err) { throw (err); }
        console.log(result);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the refactor.  I realized my hash was getting chopped by the column size in my db.  It's correctly working now

Comment: Hi, Just wondering, if we're using the async functions, do they have to be in a loop like in your example or can you separate the hashing and the comparing in two methods.

Comment: I have the same issue and am wondering if it causes issues if one sets the `hash` as a string?

Comment: for some reason I always get `false` out of `bcrypt.compare`, a naive `==` as well as the function in the library `buffer-equal-constant-time` gives `true` (which is correct), giving up on `bcrypt` here.

Comment: giving 10 number as second argument of the .hash() gives error at runtime.

Comment: i guess no need to create hash you can simply compare password too.

Comment: @gal-ben-haim can you explain why genSalt needs to be skipped here? That's not what the examples state. I understand the second parameter 10 will try other salts, but not clear why the first method won't work.

Comment: @Gal, had the same issue here, but I was using procedures to insert data (the procedure chopped my string), so it's clever to also check the data type in your procedure parameters too.

Answer (score 15):

Arguments for bcrypt's compare method should be

`bcrypt.compare(actual_password, encrypted_password)`

instead of

`bcrypt.compare(encrypted_password, actual_password)`

=> the encrypted_password should be the second argument.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 

Answer (score 13):

I dont know if you have the same as I did, I had the same problem because my table had the length of 45 chars and  bcrypt compares if the hash lenght is diferent from 60 it returns false. Just increase the length of characters in your table

Answer (score 7):

Mine was due to my database column not having a large enough varchar length. A good place to check.

Comment: For me the issue was due to a newline in the password in the database.

Answer (score 6):

For me it was just an arguments disorder

The right order

```
bcrypt.compare(plainPasswordToCheck, hashedPasswordOnStorage)
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. After changing the node package from `bcrypt` to `bcryptjs` the comparision worked like a charm. Since the package seems to be a fork, the functions do not need to be adjusted.

Comment: This was the solution for me as well.

Answer (score 2):

i dont know if you have the same as I did, I had the same problem because my table had the length of 35 chars and bcrypt compares if the hash lenght is diferent from 60 it returns false. Just increase the length of characters in your table

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem, but I am sure I am not encoding my password twice. Here is the thing.
bcrypt-nodejs npm package is on v0.0.3 and I am using this version. I am writing the algorithm to store a user password on register and read a user password on login.
The frontend is a simple  with input text for email field and input password for password field. When I submit the request I POST a call to https://localhost... on my local node server. I can log the data received and I can see the password logged is the same as the password inserted on frontend.

The code used to store the password is:

```
//var user.bcrypt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(10);;
var clearPwd = user.password;
user.password = bcrypt.hashSync(clearPwd);//, user.bcrypt);
log4.debug("hashSyncked: "+ user.password);
db.userSave(user, cb);
```

The code used to read and compare password is:

```
log4.debug('compare '+pwd+' with saved on db for user %j', userDoc.password);
var okPwd = bcrypt.compareSync(pwd, userDoc.password);
```

So, I see the hashed password, it is logged as a string like $ert3435tF.02ri etc...

But everytime I login with the same password I registered with, **okPwd** is always false. Why?

Even if I un-comment the commented code!

**UPDATE**
The solution I found was about methods. Password should not be stored and read like that, it is too ...rude !! The correct method is mentioned [here](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/32866457221/password-authentication-with-mongoose-part-1) Watch out! There is an error in that guideline. bcrypt.hash(...) functions needs 2 object parameter and 2 callbacks! The last one is the one called at the end of the hash process, the first is called to track the hash proces. I put that a **null** and it all works well.
I admit I made another mistake: I used bcrypt-nodejs package instead of brcrypt.

Answer (score 1):

Just modify the length of characters in your database assign to password field, maybe the hash generated is more larger than the field can support

Comment: Hello and Welcome to StackOverflow! Have you read [how do I give a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). It should help you avoid being downvoted.

Answer (score 1):

my hash was starting with $2y and it had to start with $2b

> This library supports $2a$ and $2b$ prefix bcrypt hashes. $2x$ and
>   $2y$ hashes are specific to bcrypt implementation developed for John
>   the Ripper. In theory, they should be compatible with $2b$ prefix.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was passing in the hash as a command line argument to a node program - just for testing:

```
node admin/bcrypt.js password $2b$10$/v9nAxpPQoDH5LMa/q.0AON/gEk.AxF57hHtIGkKR5IAWfMLyBcmm
```

The hash started with `$2b$10$/`; the `$2` and `$1` were interpreted as positional arguments and evaluated to empty values, hence the value being compared was different than what I passed in. Escaping the `$` symbols with a `\` solved the issue:

```
node admin/bcrypt.js password \$2b\$10\$/v9nAxpPQoDH5LMa/q.0AON/gEk.AxF57hHtIGkKR5IAWfMLyBcmm
```

Answer (score 1):

Very easy to mix up the order in the compare function ;)

```
bcrypt.compare(user_entered_password, database_encrypted_password)
```

Comment: This answer is a duplicate of an existing answer

Comment: Utterly useless answer.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with postgresql, but should always be the same.

I simply had to trim my db result:

```js
bcrypt.compare(
    req.body.password,
    String(user.PASSWORD).trim()
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

```
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
var salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync();

bcrypt.hash('mypassword', salt, function(err, hash){
    if(err) throw err;

    bcrypt.compare('mypassword', hash, function(err, result) {
      if (err) { throw (err); }
      console.log(result);
    });

});
```

Comment: The question was about bcrypt.compare.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and for me the solution was to fix a typo in my frontend. I was sending 'pasword' from my form and expecting 'password'. Somehow bcyppt then hashed the returned undefined value and that was the reason compare() always returned false.

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution which worked for me is if in your User model you put under password field.

```
lowercase: true,
```

I happened to had this one copied from another field. When I removed it the issue disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

I deleted my user and recreated it and did this

```
const isMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
console.log(user.password, isMatch);
if (!isMatch) {
  return res.status(400).json({
    msg:
      "Sorry, your password was incorrect. Please double-check your password.",
  });
```

and at the time of creating a user, I did this

```
const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
user.password = await bcrypt.hash(password, salt);
```

Answer (score 0):

In the compare function, you do not need to generate a new hash, do this:

```
async function Login(email, password) {
  const user = await this.service.getByEmail(email);

  const passwordBd = user.user_password;

  const matching = await bcrypt.compare(password, passwordBd);

  console.log(matching); //true
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was that in schema type option for password, i set lowercase to true...after removing lowercase set to true for my password schema type option and dropping the collection using compass and recreating the collection, bcrypt is working fine....

Answer (score 0):

This is not a common case but I found I was hashing twice when saving my admin user, you might wanna check that out.

Answer (score 0):

What I did is dropping the first table created "users", create a new one with the same name "users" and it's working great. In my pgAdmin4 the Bob's password which is simply "bob" was showing the word: bob instead of the password's hash. that's it !!!

In Terminal:

```
jwtdb=# DROP TABLE users;
DROP TABLE
jwtdb=# \dt
Did not find any relations.
jwtdb=# CREATE TABLE users(
  user_id uuid PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),
  user_name TEXT NOT NULL,
  user_email TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  user_password TEXT NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE
```

After:

#### Create a USER 1

```
send request
POST http://localhost:5000/api/users
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "name": "Bob",
  "email" : "bob@email.com",
  "password": "bob"
}
```

[image: And Finally the magic played]

Answer (score -3):

That was due to password length 45, increase it and that solves the issue.

Comment: This has already been mentioned in other answers such as https://stackoverflow.com/a/41431982/2227743