# Node.js Login using Bcrypt Library

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, ionic-framework, bcrypt

In everycase it returns value as false...
  Versions used
  node - 10.14.1
  npm - 6.4.1
  bcrypt : 3.0.0
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DAk1x.png)Framework @ionicFramework

Comment: you should add the code in the question not in a pic...

Answer (score 0):

Try using hash instead of genSalt. There is an accepted solution already.

[Node bcrypt's compare always returns false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14795130/node-bcrypts-compare-always-returns-false)

Hope this helps.