# await bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user.password) return false

Tags: node.js, mongodb, authentication, bcrypt, password-hash

**The bcrypt.compare returns false always when it compares the result from the DB with the string password.**

Hi Dear, I am trying to create a login authentication for my form. I create the user with a hash password and then I am trying to log in but during to compare plain text password and hashed password bcrypt.compare return false.

When I create a hash password and compare it in the same function it works well but if I take the hash password from the DB again it returns false.

```
     const myFunction = async ()=>{
    const passwordText = 'abcd123'
    const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(passwordText, 10)
    console.log(passwordText)
    console.log(hashedPassword)
    const isMatch = await bcrypt.compare(passwordText, hashedPassword)
    console.log(isMatch)
}

myFunction()
```

Out Put

```
abcd123
$2b$10$yNuWJBqlV8NjHrmqOfwaSuKDk.rSB9O6KstAmUpS2770GC1Nlyjw.
true
```

But when I create user with a hash password like this

```
router.post('/user/signup', async (req, res)=>{


try{
    const user = new User(req.body)

    const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10)
    user.password = await bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt)
    
    await user.save().then((user)=>{
        res.status(201).send(user)
    }).catch((e)=>{
        res.send(e)
    })
} catch(e){
    res.status(500).send()
}
})
```

and when I compare it in log in route it returns false

```
router.post("/user/login", async (req, res) => {
const body = req.body;
const user = await User.findOne({ email: body.email });
if (user) {
  // check user password with hashed password stored in the database
  const validPassword = await bcrypt.compare(body.password, user.password);
  if (validPassword) {
    res.status(200).json({ message: "Valid password" });
  } else {
    res.status(400).json({ error: "Invalid Password" });
  }
} else {
  res.status(401).json({ error: "User does not exist" });
}
```

});

I tried to create a hash password in user schema like this

```
userSchema.pre('save', async function(next){
const user = this
if(user.isModified('password')){
    user.password = await bcrypt.hash(user.password, 10)
} 
console.log('Befor saveing')
next()
```

})

again it returns false.

I will appreciate any help, thanks.

**Update and Solution**

Finally, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62375275/14570627) post solve my problem, everything is working.
When I create a user in the password field I used `lowercase: true,` and after that, I remove this now bcrypt compare is working I got `True` return.

Answer (score 0):

I will share my solution, I hope to help you.

**LOGIN**

```
exports.ValidateUser = async (req, res, next) => {
     const user = await User.findOne({email:req.query.email});
     if(user !== null){
        const verify_password = await bcrypt.compare(req.query.password,user.password);
        if(verify_password){
            const token = await generateToken(user);
            res.header("x-auth-token",token).send({
                token:token
            });
        }else{
            res.status(400).send({message:'Wrong email or password.'});
        }
    }else{
         res.status(404).send({message:"User not found."})
     }
}
```

**Create User**

```
exports.createUser = async (req,res,next) => {

    const user = new User({first_name: req.body.first_name,
        last_name: req.body.last_name,
        email: req.body.email,
        password: await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10),
        roles:req.body.roles});

    user.save().then(()=>{
        res.status(201).send({message:"User created."})
    }).catch((error)=>{
        res.status(400).send({error:error});
    });
}
```

Comment: Is const verify_password = await bcrypt.compare(req.query.password,user.password); work for you it return false for me